# How to create a iOS Shortcut which sends a photo as a message without any user interaction

Tags: iphone, ios, shortcuts-app

I am using the [Shortcuts app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/shortcuts/id915249334) for iOS and would like to create a very simple two-step shortcut:

1. Take a picture using the iPhone's camera
2. Send that picture to a specific contact via iMessage.

I found actions for doing both:

[image]

Initially I had a problem with the Camera UI showing up and waiting for the button press but that was solved by unchecking Show Camera Preview.

Unfortunately the send iMessage step also displays the iMessage UI. The input photo is correctly recognized and entered into the message, but then iMessage opens and waits for me to type more text or send the message myself.

This is despite the Show When Run switch being off which I expected would be its function because I don't know what else it would be doing beside not showing the app when the step is running.

Any ideas on how to make it so the message is sent automatically without any user interaction?

Comment: This is the same as https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371451/how-to-send-a-photo-with-shortcut-ios-app-without-needing-confirmation Seems reasonable to me that messages can't be sent without user interaction - if only to protect the message network. Save to Dropbox works without user interaction.