# How to send a photo with Shortcut iOS app without needing confirmation

Tags: iphone, ios, shortcut, automation, shortcuts-app

The attached image shows the setup within the iOS shortcut app. I'm trying to have the shortcut take a photo and send it to a predetermined number. It works fine, except for the fact that I have to complete the action manually by pressing send. So the shortcut takes the photo and loads the SMS message but at that point it stops, waiting for me to press send.

How do I automate this last step?

[image: shortcut setup]

This is where the shortcut ends, waiting for me to press send.

[image]

Comment: Is it allowed by the OS to send any messages without permission? let me dig up some documentation..

Comment: I think so because it works if no photo is attached

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284599/locking-the-fields-in-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/6287412#6287412 Turns out in some cases, emails I guess, it is allowed. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Comment: Thanks. I ended up getting it to save to Dropbox instead as I don't have the default mail app installed.